# How to position the labelText inside a textfield?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I would like to move the label text to the `topLeft` position.

From this, to this.

[image: Now:]
[image: What I wanted:]

Code:

```dart
Container buildPendingPageTextField() {
return Container(
  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  child: TextField(
    textAlign: TextAlign.start,
    controller: attendanceBloc.refusedReasonController,
    textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
    maxLines: 3,
    minLines: 3,
    scrollPhysics: ScrollPhysics(),
    style: TextStyle(
      height: 1,
      fontSize: 15,
      letterSpacing: -0.5,
    ),
    decoration: InputDecoration(
      errorText: attendanceBloc.error.value,
      floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never,
      labelText: "Descreva aqui o motivo",
      labelStyle: TextStyle(),
      border: const OutlineInputBorder(
        borderSide: BorderSide(
          color: Colors.grey,
          width: 0.3,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);

}
```

I have tried aligment on the container. on the `inputDecoration`, and even on `textStyle`, no success.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### [alignLabelWithHint property](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/InputDecoration/alignLabelWithHint.html)

> Typically set to true when the InputDecorator contains a multiline TextField (TextField.maxLines is null or > 1) to override the default behavior of aligning the label with the center of the TextField.

You should set `alignLabelWithHint` to true to override the default behavior of aligning the label with the center:

```
decoration: InputDecoration(
  errorText: attendanceBloc.error.value,
  floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.never,
  labelText: "Descreva aqui o motivo",
  labelStyle: TextStyle(),
  alignLabelWithHint: true, // Insert this line
  border: OutlineInputBorder(
     borderSide: BorderSide(
     color: Colors.grey,
     width: 0.3,
   ),
  ),
),
```

Comment: this almost work, but the text are still a little far, is like he have padding, but he doest.

Comment: oh wait, he actualy have. i add this line
contentPadding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 25, left: 10),

thanks

Answer (score 1):

`lableText` shouldn't be used for such a situation,

instead, use `hintText` to do it with less code

```
              decoration: InputDecoration(
                hintText: 'Descreva aqui o motivo',
                border: OutlineInputBorder(
                  borderSide: BorderSide(
                    color: Colors.grey,
                    width: 0.3,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

[image]

Comment: why? 
(just filling the minimum characters);

Comment: it's a better approach to do this